# What are these things on the horizontal stabilizer on a Diamond DA40?

Tags: feature-identification, horizontal-stabilizer, diamond-da40

What are these things encircled on the horizontal stabilizer on the Diamond DA40? And why are they used from an aerodynamic point of view?

[image: Diamond DA40 Diamond Star]

Source: [grupooneair.com](https://www.grupooneair.com/aviation-school-spain/)

Answer (score 5):

As explained in a related post:

*The canted tips of the original DA42 are working like an anhedral and create a compensating positive rolling moment for the vertical tail's negative sideslip-induced rolling moment. Ideally, the whole horizontal tail would have anhedral, but it was preferred to keep the elevator hinge line straight.*

From: [Why don't horizontal stabilizers have winglets?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3382/why-dont-horizontal-stabilizers-have-winglets/11784#11784)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the eloquent discussion of reducing "negative side-slip induced rolling moments" (putting larger spats on the wheels would do that too), delving into the lost art of horizontal stabilizer design has yielded an interesting thought:

Under normal flight conditions the tail usually exerts a *downforce* to keep the center of pressure aligned (longitudinally) with the center of gravity.

However, in situations of excessive positive AoA, such as stall/spin events, tail **upforce** is required to help the nose down.  Putting anhedralled endplates on the tail is a rather ingenious way of making the tail "bigger" (greater coefficient of lift) when saving upforce is needed, while making the tail "smaller" (lower drag coefficient-vortex mitigation) in a normal flight regime where **downforce** is required.

Comment: Inspired by what a young Clarence Kelly Johnson did with a new airplane that had large nacelles *ahead of the wing*.  Changing the smaller 3 fin tail of the Lockheed Electra into an end-plated horizontal stabilizer (with 2 vertical fins) greatly improved the stability characteristics.